# Possibility of adding a Morse code tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

In both my own puzzles, and in other people's puzzles, I have noticed a lot of Morse code. Obviously, going overboard with this or other common puzzle-making devices can detract from how fun the puzzle is. But there are some pretty fun ways to use Morse code that can make it less obvious that Morse code is being used.

For example, in one of my [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92091/density-type-puzzle), I made use of the official lengths of dots and dashes, as well as the lengths of pauses between them and between letters to make a Morse code part that consists only of dots, and you have to use the amount of black and white dots to find the answer. I have seen other puzzles in which Morse code is used, either in a creative way, or simply in a fun puzzle, and I see it used enough, and use it often myself, that I feel it merits its own tag.

Puzzle creators extremely often use tags to hint at the kind of puzzle, as well as the methodology used to make and/or solve it. Having a Morse code tag would allow them to convey that fact as well. I feel this way, and I would like to know how others feel about this as well.

Edit: As I was making this question, I checked to see if a Morse code tag had been added, and I accidentally added one. I mention this because I know that moderators will be able to see that I made a tag, and I wanted to start a discussion on it and basically get the moderators' permission before I went ahead and made the tag so that I wouldn't overstep my authority (or lack of it), seeing as the moderators are the ones who are supposed to keep order and oversee things around here.

Comment: Creating new tags is one of the features you unlock just by getting enough reputation, so you haven't overstepped any bounds. (And really, it's the whole community you should be asking, not the moderators - decisions are largely made by the community here on meta, and we're mostly just here for the special cases.) But it's definitely good to ask if you're unsure, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, a tag for Morse code isn't likely to be useful.

The purpose of tags is not to give hints as to what questions might involve (though they might happen to indirectly provide one). Tags are here for efficiently filtering and sorting questions -- their primary usage is for both *trying to find questions* (in searches) and for *prioritizing or hiding specific questions* (using the "tag watching" feature, available in your settings).

My general personal guideline is that I'll add a tag only if it could be useful for both of those. A [morse-code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morse-code) tag may be useful for finding questions (though I don't think "morse code" is often a prominent enough feature that it would be what people remember). But I don't think it would be useful for highlighting or hiding questions. I can't imagine anyone specifically seeing [morse-code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morse-code) and jumping on a puzzle because of it, or specifically not wanting to see questions that involve Morse code. So I don't think it would be particularly useful to have as a tag.

Comment: Makes sense. I just wanted to see how other people felt about it. Thanks for the clarification.